# Find the parameter of eigenvector as a function of given value

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, physics

I have been stuck on this question for the majority of the day, and I just cant see how part b) is possible.

question is conveyed correctly [image]

So solving the characteristic polynomial I get 
$$\hat{H}\:\:E_n\mid E\,\rangle= E_n\mid E\,\rangle$$

Re-arranging and applying the identity matrix 
$$\hat{H}\:\:E_n\mid E\,\rangle-\:E_n\mid E\,\rangle=0$$

simplifying
$$\hat H -IE_n=0$$

$$\begin{pmatrix}\mu &-\mu \\ -\mu &2\mu \end{pmatrix}-E_n\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\ 0&1\end{pmatrix}=0$$

subtracting the matrices and finding the detriment I have  the following characteristic equation.

$$\left(\mu -E_n\right)\left(2\mu -E_n\right)-\left(-\mu \right)\left(-\mu \right)=E_{n}^2-3\mu E_n+\mu ^2=0$$

Char Polynomial

$$E_{n}^2-3\mu E_n+\mu ^2=0$$

Solving the polynomial I et  the roots

$$E_0=-\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{5}-3\right)\mu \:,\:E_1=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{5}+3\right)\mu$$

and this is where I am now stumped because how can you **b** in terms of $$\mu$$ because if I use the roots to find the eigenvector like so:

$$\begin{pmatrix}\mu &-\mu \\ -\mu &2\mu \:\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}A\\ B\end{pmatrix}=-\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{5}-3\right)\mu \begin{pmatrix}A\\ B\end{pmatrix}$$

$$A\mu -B\mu =-\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{5}-3\right)\mu \:A\:$$

solving for B

I get

$$\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}A=B\:\:$$

Setting A=1, I get the eigenvector for energy in ground state to be

$$|0> =\begin{pmatrix}1\\ \frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\end{pmatrix}$$

From this I then set the two eignevector equation equal to each other

$$C\begin{pmatrix}1\\ \frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\end{pmatrix}=N_0\begin{pmatrix}1\\ \frac{1}{2}-b\end{pmatrix},\:C=N$$

And as C=N due to them being the same normalising constant they cancel out

$$\begin{pmatrix}1\\ \frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\ \frac{1}{2}-b\end{pmatrix}$$

But how I make be a function of $$\mu$$ is confusing me because there is no $$\mu$$ in either of these questions.

Comment: It does seem like the $\mu$s factor out.

Comment: have i read the question wrong in anyway?

Comment: If so, then we both have.

Comment: If $v$ is an eigenvector of a matrix $M$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $v$ is also an eigenvector of $\mu M$ with eigenvalue $\mu\lambda$. Since $\mu$ can be factored out of $\hat H$, the eigenvectors will not be dependent on it. Therefore $b$ is a "constant function of $\mu$". It is possible they phrased it this way to not give away hints.

Comment: So if that is the case surely I can write the ans as the form. $b(\mu)=\frac{2-\sqrt{5}}{2}\mu $. The reason I say this because the by scaling the eigenvector by any constant in this case $\mu$ it is still an eigenvector it just been extend in the same direction. But is it okay to give the ans I have given ^^ or is there a justification I should show for this? But why is it that the 1 in the eigenvector not a $\mu$?